# Is it possible to stream sound over Bluetooth like a phone conversation?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth

Hope you have more experience in this. Since some cars doesn't support music streaming over Bluetooth but do support the phone conversation I was wondering if it could be possible to fake a conversation so I can stream music anyway. If there is little chance this is possible I will develop an app. Does anybody have a clue, or maybe a different suggestion, or is it the Bluetooth standard that doesn't allow this, although it is using 802.11n.